# product search filter by store

Tags: walmart-api

The Walmart Open API doesn't seem to honor storeID as a filter parameter.
For example, I want my backend code (java) to search for BREAD filtered to a particular store. Is this possible with Any Open API ?

Here is my query

https://developer.api.walmart.com/api-proxy/service/affil/product/v2/searchquery=bread&facet=on&facet.filter=brand:Wonder&numItems=3&storeId=5294

The returned result seems to always ignore the storeId.

Any thoughts ?